# Data lost on MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

My code executes 10000 rows.

**Mapper pseudo-code:**

```
int rows=0;
map()
   {rows++}  
cleanup(Context c)
   {print(rows)}
```

This code prints:

```
2669
3354
3353
621
(sum=9997)
```

Why the sum is 9997?

**Reducer pseudo-code:**

```
int rows=0;
reduce()
   {rows++}  
cleanup(Context c)
   {print(rows)}
```

The reducer prints:
3354

Where is all the other data?

**Edit 1**

I have found the main problem.

My fault is that the key that is sent is the number of the row. When the mapper calls the `cleanup()` function, it resets the counter of rows (held in the driver of the application). Therefore the key isn't unique. Can I resolve that by sending the key from the parameters of the map function? I don't think the `cleanup()` resets this parameter.

If instead I use a global variable in the driver of the application, is there a synchronization problem?

**Edit 2**

My code executes 10000 rows (and 1 header line)

**Driver pseudo-code:**

```
public static enum COUNTER {ROW};
```

**Mapper pseudo-code:**

```
map()
   {row=context.getCounter(RWDriver.COUNTER.ROW).increment(1);
    context.write(row,new Text(...))
   }     
cleanup(Context c)
   {print(c.getCounter(RWDriver.COUNTER.ROW).getValue());}
```

This code prints:

```
2670
3355
3354
622
(sum=10001 correct)
```

After 2670,3355, the buffer is full and MapReduce automatically resets the counter ROW to 0. I need the actual number of rows, but this method don't work.

Comment: Can you share Map Reduce counter values ?

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of the Data might be wrong .

You should either use Map-Reduce Framework Counters or user defined counters :

---

### Map-Reduce Framework Counters

```
Map input records
Map output records
Map output bytes
Reduce input groups
Reduce input records
Reduce output records
```

---

### User Defined Counter

```
class mapper()
{
static enum Counters { INPUT_LINES }
map()
{
  context.getCounter(Counters.INPUT_LINES).increment(1);
}
```

similarly in Reducer too .

### Get your value of counters

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
Job job = Job.getInstance(cluster,conf);
result = job.waitForCompletion(true);
...
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
for (CounterGroup group : counters) {
  System.out.println("* Counter Group: " + group.getDisplayName() + " (" + group.getName() + ")");
  System.out.println("  number of counters in this group: " + group.size());
  for (Counter counter : group) {
    System.out.println("  - " + counter.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter.getName() + ": "+counter.getValue());
  }
}
```